# Last 10 days of work is lost after git push --force

Tags: git, git-lfs, bitbucket-cloud

I tried to add pattern to GIT LFS today and all the work in the last 10 days are gone!!! The last commit seen is 11th Nov. All the work in between are all gone!!!

Last week I added *.html to GIT LFS. Today I tried to add *.{html, svg} and this is what I get!

```
$ g reflog show --all
a7406c404 (HEAD -> UpgradeDotNetCore, origin/UpgradeDotNetCore) refs/remotes/origin/UpgradeDotNetCore@{0}: update by push
a7406c404 (HEAD -> UpgradeDotNetCore, origin/UpgradeDotNetCore) refs/heads/UpgradeDotNetCore@{0}: commit: Fix GIT
a7406c404 (HEAD -> UpgradeDotNetCore, origin/UpgradeDotNetCore) HEAD@{0}: commit: Fix GIT
1eaf71063 refs/remotes/origin/UpgradeDotNetCore@{1}: update by push
1eaf71063 refs/heads/UpgradeDotNetCore@{1}: commit: Track wwwroot
1eaf71063 HEAD@{1}: commit: Track wwwroot
207186a6c refs/heads/UpgradeDotNetCore@{2}: branch: Created from refs/remotes/origin/UpgradeDotNetCore
207186a6c HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from dev to UpgradeDotNetCore
be3b63495 (origin/dev, origin/HEAD, dev) refs/heads/dev@{0}: clone: from https://kokhow@bitbucket.org/4xlabs/bz-frontend.git
be3b63495 (origin/dev, origin/HEAD, dev) refs/remotes/origin/HEAD@{0}: clone: from https://kokhow@bitbucket.org/4xlabs/bz-frontend.git
be3b63495 (origin/dev, origin/HEAD, dev) HEAD@{3}: clone: from https://kokhow@bitbucket.org/4xlabs/bz-frontend.git
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: You'd most likely need the ref-log of the origin repository and hope entries haven't been cleaned-up.

Comment: Do you mean `git reflog origin`?

Comment: Why would you add HTML and SVG files to LFS? Those are diffable, compressable text, not binaries. Git LFS is intended for binary content.